# Using View.performClick invalid in activity by ButterKnife

Tags: android, butterknife

when I click checkAnswerBtn button, it should to show log "playing" ,but not. So butterKnife cannot support this way?

```
@Bind(R.id.checkAnswerBtn) Button checkAnswerBtn;
@Bind(R.id.mainPlayBtn) ImageButton mainPlayBtn;
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activitylayout);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
...
}

@OnClick(R.id.checkAnswerBtn)
void onCheckAnswerBtnClicked() {
     mainPlayBtn.performClick();
}

@OnClick(R.id.mainPlayBtn)
void onMainPlayBtn() {
     Log.e(TAG, "playing");
}
```

Comment: why are you calling performClick instead of simply performing the operation?

Comment: mm...I just want to know why this way is not work, thank you~

Answer (score 1):

```
 @OnClick(R.id.checkAnswerBtn)
   void onCheckAnswerBtnClicked() {
   onMainPlayBtn();
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
@OnClick(R.id.checkAnswerBtn)
void onCheckAnswerBtnClicked(View view) {
    mainPlayBtn.performClick();
}
```

Pass view object in click method.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure in layout file you have defined on the onClick attribute on ImageButton

```
  @OnClick(R.id.checkAnswerBtn)
    void onCheckAnswerBtnClicked(View view) {
        view.performClick();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the onCreate you can use

```
checkAnswerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.e(TAG, "playing");
            }
        });
```

So on clicking the checkAnswerBtn it shows "playing" in log then why using such complex method?

**or**

you could write interface and listner so it works in way you wish!

Comment: thank you ! I just want to why this way isn' t work, maybe it's really stupidXD

Comment: You can click a button programmatically by using the button.performClick() method.Debug and check whether  mainPlayBtn.performClick(); function is called if yes then butterKnife wouldn't have considered the programatic click

Comment: Which version of butterknife are you using?

Comment: com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1.